# Need help in converting String to Date format in Sybase

Tags: datetime, sybase, date-format

I am trying to convert two types of string into date format, however not able to do either of them.

The problematic input strings with expected output are as follows:

---

**Input 1:** 20100614191522

**Expected output 1:** 6/14/2010 7:15:22 PM

---

**Input 2:** 2010/12

**Expected output 2:** 12/1/2010 12:00:00 AM

---

I tried like ,

```
select convert(datetime,'20100614191522',109)
```

I tried with different style parameters with "convert" function . But I always get following errors. 
*Syntax error during explicit conversion of VARCHAR value '20100614191522' to a DATETIME field.
Msg: 249, Level: 16, State: 1*

Can you please help me out, how to achieve the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The style parameters that you have tried is for converting `datetime data` to a character type. Here you are asking for the opposite convertion.

Input 1

```
declare @str varchar(20)
set @str = '20100614191522'
select convert(datetime,substring(@str, 5, 2 ) + '/' + substring(@str, 7, 2 ) + '/' + substring(@str, 1, 4 )  + ' ' + substring(@str, 9, 2 )  + ':' + substring(@str, 11, 2 ) + ':' + substring(@str, 13, 2 ) )
```

gives

```
Jun 14 2010  7:15PM
```

Input 2

```
declare @str varchar(20)
set @str = '2010/12'
select convert(datetime, @str + '/01')
```

gives

```
Dec  1 2010 12:00AM
```

Comment: This works well but is there any latest methods to facilitate the same functionality..